# UIScrollView autoresizemask is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my code which shown below, I am creating a scroll view and adding an Image View in it. Unfortunately autoresizingmask is not working and the image shown on a portion of the screen. The code is shown below:

```
// Scroll View Setup
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 216, 300, 344)];
self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
self.scrollView.bounces = YES;
self.scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
self.scrollView.opaque = YES;
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.scrollView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 344);
self.scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

// Image View setup
self.pgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 344)];
self.pgImage.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
self.pgImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.pgImage.opaque = YES;
self.pgImage.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.pgImage.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
self.pgImage.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.pgImage];

//autoresize scrollView
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
CGFloat scrollViewWidth = 0.0f;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    CGFloat height = (view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y);
    scrollViewHeight = ((height > scrollViewHeight) ? height : scrollViewHeight);
    CGFloat width = (view.frame.size.width + view.frame.origin.x);
    scrollViewWidth = ((width > scrollViewWidth) ? width : scrollViewWidth);
}

[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))];
```

For me it seams OK, but may be something is missing. Your assistance is welcomed. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What your exception of UI (pgImage)   in portrait mode.

Comment: UI is always in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autolayout`. Add `UIView` in `ScrollView` and then add your `ImageView` on it.

Comment: thanks. It worked but without autolayout, just following the rest.

Comment: that's cool. :) Use of autolayout can make this kind of stuff much simpler..!